# how to remove duplicates and leave one row containing value in another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

| ID | CAR | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Audi1 | F |
| 20 | BMW1 | nan |
| 50 | BMW2 | nan |
| 10 | Audi2 | nan |
| 30 | Mazda | F |
| 10 | Audi3 | F |
| 20 | BMW3 | Z |
| 20 | BMW4 | F |
| 20 | BMW5 | A |
| 40 | KIA | G |
| 10 | Audi4 | A |
| 10 | Audi5 | G |
| 10 | Audi6 | nan |

i would like deleate all duplicates(in cloumn ID), and leave only one row that has F in the `TYPE` column

It should looks like:

```
| ID | CAR   | TYPE |
|----|-------|------|
| 10 | Audi1  | F    |
| 20 | BMW   | F    |
| 30 | Mazda | F    |
| 40 | KIA   | G    |
| 50 | BMW   |  nan |
```

and i need index of deleated rows

Comment: Try the logic I've added & Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Do step by step.
Remove all the numbers from column `CAR` and filter based on Keyword

```
df["mask"]=df["TYPE"].str.contains("F")
df=df.sort_values("mask", ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset="ID", keep="first").drop(columns=["mask"])

print(df)
```

output # Tested

```
   ID    CAR TYPE
0  10  Audi1    F
4  30  mAZDA    F
7  20   BMW4    F
9  40    kIA    G
2  50   BMW2  NaN
>>>
```

Comment: it doesn't work `keep='first'` leave the first row whether or not TYPE is F

Comment: Ahh ok sorry missed that Know tested

Comment: Try this and let me know @AnnAc0nda

Comment: Have you tested?